# Malware application in Android

Tags: android, malware, dynamic-analysis, apk, audio

Is there some website that give us the possibility to download malware APK in order to study it? I’m interested to study the abuse of android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO in Android 8.

Comment: https://bazaar.abuse.ch/browse.php?search=file_type%3Aapk

Answer (score 2):

- [Koodous](https://koodous.com/pro) has a huge collection of apks, searching in "detected" category may give you what you wanted.
- [VirusShare](https://virusshare.com/about) is a general malware collection, requires registration, as far as I remember they have torrent tracker [here](http://tracker.virusshare.com:6969/) and there are android-specific sample collection per year. I never tried to download something from there, but you can try.
- There are some collections on github, for example [here](https://github.com/ashishb/android-malware)
- [malware bazaar](https://bazaar.abuse.ch/browse.php?search=file_type%3Aapk) - not too large collection, but better than nothing.
- [Pithus](https://beta.pithus.org/) - requires registration via github, allows apk search by permission, allows download when logged in.

Koodous requires to pay for access, most basic access that includes downloading costs around EUR 60 for month.

Good luck.

Comment: Why are you helping him? Do you want yet another malware released to the world?

Comment: @RohitGupta getting samples is how people learn to defeat malware... I used to be a malware researcher and I started this way, then worked at several anti-malware companies. Don't make assumptions, plus if that's his intent, he'll figure out a way to do it regardless... not every gun owner is a murderer. I'd be more worried if he was looking for Android 13.