# Malware apk in Android

Tags: android, malware, apk, audio

Is there some website where i'm able to find malware apk filtering by permission (for instance: RECORD_AUDIO)? I'm looking for website similar to [pithus](https://beta.pithus.org/)

Comment: Self-dupe: [Malware application in Android](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30960/malware-application-in-android)

Comment: The question is mine. Unfortunately, in that question i didn’t find what I’m looking for. So, I redid the question in different way. @AndrewT.